# Using a localhost https redirect uri with httr package

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, httr

The default redirect uri in the `oauth_app()` function of the `httr` package is: `http://localhost:1410/`. I tried switching to `https://localhost:1410/`, but the authentication flow cannot be completed. I'm curious to know if it's possible to use HTTPS as the redirect uri. The Instagram API mentions this :

> The one thing to keep in mind is that all requests to the API must be
>   made over SSL (https:// not http://)

But then their example goes on to use an http callback registered redirect uri. I assume the answer is not really `httr` specific, but here is a reproducible example using Google OAuth 2.0:

```
library(httr)    
key <- "526767977974-i8pn4vvaga2utiqmeblfnpakflgq964n.apps.googleusercontent.com"
secret <- "tNJixXCExE30f_ARBzb6e4hC"
myapp <- oauth_app("google", key, secret, redirect_uri='https://localhost:1410/')
token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("google"),
                        myapp,
                        scope=c("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with facebook forcing strict https redirect url. I believe the solution is somewhere in httr::oauth_listener , haven't been able to figure that out yet.

Edit 1 : So in facebook / instagram setting will have to specify https://localhost:1410/. So when you authenticate it will redirect you to https://localhost:1410/ but since the httpuv server is listening on http://localhost:1410/, so if one can take that URL and replace https with http and reload the flow works. I haven't been able to do it, but trying to work on it.